# What's the reason why "Shokugeki no Souma" has so many color chapters recently?

Tags: manga-production, shokugeki-no-soma

Does anyone know why all the latest releases (about 5 chapters) of *Shokugeki no Souma* have all been in color? It's great and all, but it's starting to scare me.

For some reason, it's hard to find copies online, but I read manga on my phone and all the latest chapters are like HD full-on color.

Comment: The color chapters are exclusive to the digital version of Jump.

Answer (score 1):

The manga is normally published in the *Shonen Jump* magazine in black and white format, like the others, but the magazine has a new website called [Shonen Jump+](http://plus.shonenjump.com/) where you can buy the official color chapter to view online.

Only *One Piece* and *Naruto* eventually also have chapters in color on the web, and it's because *Shokugeki no Souma* is quite popular and as an extra for the final arc autumn election.

Comment: I tried to edit your post, but I don't understand the second half of your post. And would you please cite some source?